# filtering the data according to data in angular4

Tags: angular

I have to filter data using angular 4? Its an women apparel site. For example I have to filter women's T-shirt according to size, colour and sleeve length. so there is a 10+size, 6+colour,3+sleeve length. Now if I click on blue then all women's T-shirt  of blue should be shown and also the size when I click on size xl  then all women's T-shirt of xl should be shown

```
app.component.html

<div class="col-md-6" id="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" routerlink="#submenu" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="toggle1()" data-target="#submenu">Color <mat-icon class="pull-right" >{{icon1 ? 'remove' : 'add' }}</mat-icon></a>
       <div class="collapse" id="submenu" aria-expanded="false">
         <ul class="nav" *ngFor="let colour of colours ">
           <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" (click)="Event(colour)" routerlink="/">{{colour.title}}</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerlink="#submenu2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu2">sleeve-length <mat-icon class="pull-right" >add</mat-icon></a>
      <div class="collapse" id="submenu2" aria-expanded="false">
        <ul class="nav" *ngFor="let s of sleeve">
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id={{s.id}} routerlink="/">{{s.title}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerlink="#submenu3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu3">sizes<mat-icon class="pull-right" >add</mat-icon></a>
      <div class="collapse" id="submenu3" aria-expanded="false">
        <ul class="nav" *ngFor="let size of length">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id={{size.id}} routerlink="/">{{size.title}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" *ngFor="let x of httpdata; let i = index; ">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <img src="{{x.product_image}}" height="300px" width="200px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

app.component.ts

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private dataservice:DataserviceService,private global: AppGlobals){}
httpdata;
colours;
sleeve;
length;
ngOnInit() {
this.dataservice.getApparel(this.global.AppUrl +'getRecommendations?client=web&call_tag=stylemachine&size=15&position=0&attempt=0&user=5724&project=2226&collection=200&category=16&client-tag=women_apparels').subscribe(data=>this.httpdata=data);
this.dataservice.getFilter(this.global.AppUrl +'availableFilters?client=web&category=16').subscribe(colours=>this.colours=colours);
this.dataservice.getSleeve(this.global.AppUrl +'availableFilters?client=web&category=16').subscribe(sleeve=>this.sleeve=sleeve);
this.dataservice.getLength(this.global.AppUrl +'availableFilters?client=web&category=16').subscribe(length=>this.length=length);
}
Event(colour) {
console.log(colour);
}
}
```

Comment: Seeing your code would be really helpful...

Comment: Did you try creating filter pipe for the same? You can use a filter pipe or you can filter the list in the component.

Answer (score 0):

I have used one Pipes to make this kind of search and sort rule in an application I made with IONIC 3.

You can have a look on how to make PIPES in angular 4.

Otherwise, I could give you some examples.

Comment: can you  give some examples ?

Comment: for example, I used this one to allow search (filter) :

this.showedList = this.showedList.filter((v) => {
    if(v.name && q) {
      if (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  });

Comment: follow this link, it helped me : https://javebratt.com/searchbar-firebase/